# How to handle SSL certificates for implementing WhiteLabel option in a web app running on NGINX server

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl-certificate, multi-tenant, aws-acm

I'm working on a Web App.

My app runs on the subdomain `app.mydomain.com`

I need to WhiteLabel my app. I'm asking my Customers to point to their own website via CNAME to my app.

`design.customerwebsite.com` points to `app.mydomain.com`

Here is what I have tried to solve this.

I created a new file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` named `customerwebsite.com`
Added a symlink to the file.

I installed SSL using `certbot` with the below command.

`sudo certbot --nginx -n --redirect -d design.customerwebsite.com`

Here is the code for my NGINX conf file of `customerwebsite.com`

```
server
{

 server_name www.customerwebsite.com;
 return 301 $scheme://customerwebsite.com$request_uri;
}


server {

#  proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;

 listen       80;
 listen       443;

  server_name design.customerwebsite.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/design.customerwebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/design.customerwebsite.com/privkey.pem;


 root /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/dist;
  location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }

 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https' )
 {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 }


}
```

I'm successfully able to run my web app on `https://design.customerwebsite.com`

But the SSL certificate shows that it is pointed to `app.mydomain.com` and shows insecure.

My `app.mydomain.com` has SSL certificate from Amazon ACM which is attached via Load Balancer.

What should be the approach to solve this?

Comment: can you provide app.domain.com ngix configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions for this
1- add the ssl certs to the loadbalance: You need to request a cert with all the supported DNS names  (app.mydomain.com and design.customerwebsite.com)/ and you need to manage customerwebsite.com domain with Route53. I think that is not possible in your case.

2- Do not use ssl on the load balancer: for this option, we will not terminate ssl on the load balancer, however, it will be passed to nginx to handle. Your loadbalancer configs should look like

[image]

you need to generate a new ssl cert that includes both domains

```
sudo certbot --nginx -n --redirect -d app.mydomain.com -d *.mydomain.com -d design.customerwebsite.com -d *.customerwebsite.com
```

Nginx configs

```
server
{
 server_name www.customerwebsite.com;
 return 301 $scheme://customerwebsite.com$request_uri;
}


server {
 listen       80 default_server;
 server_name design.customerwebsite.com;
 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen       443 ssl default_server;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/design.customerwebsite.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/design.customerwebsite.com/privkey.pem;

  server_name design.customerwebsite.com;
  root /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/dist;

  location / {
      resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the elements provided to the ACM Load Balancer must match every domain on which you may receive requests. In the certificate, you should have a Subject Alternate Name containing every matching domain.

For example  on stackoverflow.com, the certificate has a CN *.stackexchange.com but has that Subject Alternative Name :

```
DNS:*.askubuntu.com, DNS:*.blogoverflow.com, DNS:*.mathoverflow.net, DNS:*.meta.stackexchange.com, DNS:*.meta.stackoverflow.com, DNS:*.serverfault.com, DNS:*.sstatic.net, DNS:*.stackexchange.com, DNS:*.stackoverflow.com, DNS:*.stackoverflow.email, DNS:*.superuser.com, DNS:askubuntu.com, DNS:blogoverflow.com, DNS:mathoverflow.net, DNS:openid.stackauth.com, DNS:serverfault.com, DNS:sstatic.net, DNS:stackapps.com, DNS:stackauth.com, DNS:stackexchange.com, DNS:stackoverflow.blog, DNS:stackoverflow.com, DNS:stackoverflow.email, DNS:stacksnippets.net, DNS:superuser.com
```

Comment: Any idea on how to implement this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

you're forgetting some details ...
you have to do a configuration for the domain

**/////// app.myDominio.com ////////**

just as you did for the normal domain and also create SSL only for this domain. You can use the let script.
Configure a path for the NGINX LOG so you can check for errors that NGINX detects.

You can also use it in the NGINX settings
* .domain.com
(where * means app, maybe it detects)